# Problem in handle PNG by the PIL

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import ImageFile as PILImageFile

p = PILImageFile.Parser()

#Parser the data
for chunk in content.chunks():
    p.feed(chunk)    
try:
    image = p.close()
except IOError:                        
    return None
#Here the model is RGBA
if image.mode != "RGB":
    image = image.convert("RGB")
```

It always get stuck in here:

```
image = image.convert("RGB")

File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py" in convert
  653.         self.load()
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py" in load
  189.                     s = read(self.decodermaxblock)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py" in load_read
  365.         return self.fp.read(bytes)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py" in read
  300.             data = self.data[pos:pos+bytes]

Exception Type: TypeError at 
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: For other kind of picture for example jpg etc, it did not have such issue.

Answer (score 0):

This results from an incorrect coding of close within PIL, its a bug.

**Edit the File ( path may be different on your system ):**

*sudo vi /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py*

**Online 283 Modify:**

```
def close(self):
    self.data = self.offset = None
```

**Change it to:**

```
def close(self):
    #self.data = self.offset = None
    self.offset = None
```

Thats it, comment out the broken code, add the correct line, and save the file.  All done, just run the program that was failing before and it will work now.